# Hadoop YARN Job Stucked After Submission and Status Remains Undefined

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, hadoop2

I am trying to run one example MR job on my pseudo distributed cluster in virtualbox VM (RHEL 6.5, 8GB RAM, 100GB HDD) but after submission of the job It stucks there only.

> INFO: mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1437483993_001

The application tracking url (http://localhost:8088/cluster/applicationID) shows the result like this:

> User: root
>
> Name : grep-search
>
> Application-Type : mapreduce
>
> Status : Accepted
>
> FinalStatus : Undefined

What I have tried:

- modified yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml for minimum and maximum allocation for memory following the tutorial (http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/)
- ensured that disk space is free enough to accomodate new jobs.
- `jps` shows all the services are running properly.

But no luck. Please guide me through.

Edit:
Here's the log:

`[root@master ~]# hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar grep /user/pradeep output23 'dfs[a-z.]+'
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
16/04/27 10:21:09 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
16/04/27 10:21:09 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
16/04/27 10:21:09 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
16/04/27 10:21:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
16/04/27 10:21:11 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1461732411884_0001
16/04/27 10:21:11 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
16/04/27 10:21:11 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1461732411884_0001
16/04/27 10:21:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1461732411884_0001/
16/04/27 10:21:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1461732411884_0001`

Answer (score 0):

There is some other issue and not the infrastructure. Please paste what are u trying to do in the map reduce code.

Comment: I am trying to run a simple existing example application to test the infrastructure
`hadoop jar hadoop-examples.jar grep input output ‘dfs[a-z.]+'`

Comment: following your suggestion i tried running a different map-reduce code which is generated by PIG script. Still the job freezes after submitting to resorcemanager.